# UIBezierPath never being rendered

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

so I have a little experience with objective-c, but not a ton.  I'm trying to render UIBezierPath via TouchEvents (in other words draw a line with your finger).  In addition, I would like to save all the bezierPaths into a NSMutableArray (paths) so that I can move or modify them later.  This is the very simplest of applications.  My header looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIBezierPath* path;
    NSMutableArray* paths;

    int curThickness;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *scene;
@end
```

Scene is the view which takes up the entire screen and is where I am trying to draw my paths.

Relavent implementation looks like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSLog(@"Starting Path");

    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    path.lineWidth = 15.0f;
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    path.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
    path.flatness = 2.0;
    path.miterLimit = 4.0;

    [path moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:scene]];

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [path addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:scene]];
    [scene setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"I'm supposed to be drawing something...");
    [[UIColor redColor] set];
    [path stroke];
}



- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"No more touchy feelies");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [path addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:scene]];
    [paths addObject:path];
    [scene setNeedsDisplay];

    NSLog(@"number of paths: %i.", paths.count);
```

}

When I run it on the emulator, all the events are registered, DrawRect is never called, nothing is drawn on the screen (even if I add a [path trace] at the end of touchesEnded), path is nonEmpty, and paths.count remains zero no matter how many paths I trace.

What am I missing?  As always your help is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be an over simplification of your problem, but do you ever add your "scene" view as a subview to your viewcontrollers view? something to the affect of [self.view addSubview:self.scene]?

Comment: That's not the problem because I've already added a few UIButtons programmatically to scene and they show up and work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things that should help you:

1. `UIViewController` does not implement `- (void)drawRect` .. you need to be doing this code in a `UIView` subclass instead!
2. If your `paths` collection is always zero count, a common mistake causing this is when  `paths` itself is nil. (Obj-c doesn't care if you try to send messages to a nil object, it will just return a default value instead of crashing.) Double-check that you instantiated an `NSMutableArray` object and pointed `paths` to it.

Comment: the initialization was absolutely the problem for the paths.  oops.  Thanks!


Is there no way to render a UIBezierPath on the built-in UIView?  And if there isn't, do the touch methods need to be in the viewController or in the custom UIView?

Comment: @user1623346 I'm not sure what you mean by "built-in UIView"...  You can subclass UIView and link it up via the Interface Builder as you please.  Both UIView and UIViewController inherit from UIResponder so you can handle the touches wherever.